# Using variable in partial name

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of "summaries" in a loop:

```
  {{#each formSummaries}}
  {{/each}}
```

For each one I want to output a template that is named by each formSummary.name:

```
{{#each formSummaries}}
  {{partial 'forms/summaries/' + name}}
{{/each}}
```

or like this:

Controller:

```
summaryPath: 'forms/summaries' + name
```

Template:

```
{{#each formSummaries}}
  {{partial summaryPath}}
{{/each}}
```

Is it possible to do something like this with a partial? Is there a more "Ember" way of solving this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Um... yes. Did you try? ;) Using model properties to dynamically render is quintessentially `Emberiffic`. You are on the right track there. `summaryPath` should be computed on a per model basis, which will work perfectly for you.

Comment: The second option will work so long as it's a computed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handlebars looks good to me, except that I would specify an `itemController`. This will let you get fancy-pants with each rendered model through the use of computed properties and other powerful controller mechanisms.

```
{{#each formSummaries itemController='summary'}}
  {{partial summaryPath}}
{{/each}}
```

Now, `summaryPath` should be computed within that item controller. How about:

```
App.SummaryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  summaryPath: function () {
    return 'templateName_' + this.get('name'); // You can tailor this part to suit your needs.
  }.property('name') 
)};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton Matthew. That looks great. Would there be a benefit to doing this in a view? I'm pretty new to Ember so the benefits on those things confuses me.

Comment: This may sound crazy, but I would try to think within the box here and not worry too much about what benefits you most or least. Just focus on finding one pattern and one solution at a time for each feature you're building. You will learn way faster that way. :D Try it this way, and then when you have some time try it another way.

Comment: Also can I pass "name" to the new itemController from the each block?

Comment: I like that mentality.

Comment: The `itemController` has the entire model for each item! That means you can do `this.get('name')`, for example.

Comment: Happy to help! Ember is freakin' sweet once you get a hold of it.

Comment: The more I use it, the more I can see that. It's just in those dark moments when I want to bash my face through the monitor that I lose site of the freakin sweetness.